How to delete widget in Wordpress?
I would like to remove the widget that is in the attached screenshot. Recently I managed to write a short code in the additional CSS code in Wordpress. Unfortunately, I changed the theme and this code was lost. Unfortunately, I also do not remember what this shortcode was.
Does anyone know what the shortcode is to remove this widget? For the sake of convenience, I will add that I do not use any widgets, I have removed all widgets in Wordpress.
Thank you for your help!


Somewhere under 'Appearance' -> 'Widgets' you still look to have the default sidebar widgets active.
